# ASP.NET 4 WebForms Routing - Get Physical Page handling the request

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, routes

Let's assume you have the following `PageRoute`

```
routes.MapPageRoute("support", "support", "~/Support.aspx");
```

Is is possible by the following url: `http://www.domain.com/support` to understand which is the physical page handling the request? (`support.aspx`)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by 'understand which is the physical page'. However, you can get the the page URL by:

```
Page.GetRouteUrl("support", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Request.Url.LocalPath.ToString()` returns **"/Support.aspx"** when this route is being requested.