# Get the actual last modified date for the requested page in WebForms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, last-modified

I want to put the last modified date of *(the .aspx file responsible for)* the currently viewed page into a footer of a Web Forms site.

I am working on a default Web Forms template from Visual Studio 2015 and building the project for .NET 4.5. In `Site.Master`, I have modified the footer like so:

```
<footer>
    <p>
        Page last updated on:
        <asp:Label ID="modyfikacja" runat="server" Text="coś nie poszło" />
    </p>
</footer>
```

and modified `Page_Load()` method in `Site.Master.cs` like so:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string _site = Server.MapPath(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
    modyfikacja.Text = "(" + _site + ") " + File.GetLastWriteTime(_site).ToString();
}
```

Unfortunately, that **doesn't actually work** all the way through:

- when I go to `http://localhost:11111`, it correctly returns date for file path `C:\imaginelikeapathheredude\default.aspx`,
- but when I go to, say, `http://localhost:11111/About`, it attempts to get the date for file path `C:\imaginelikeapathheredude\About` - ie. web route pasted onto physical root, instead of the `C:\imaginelikeapathheredude\about.aspx` file behind the route,
- (`http://localhost:11111/contact.aspx` redirects to `http://localhost:49480/contact` and doesn't change the output of any functions mentioned in this question).

There are loads of alternative solutions to getting the file, proposed all over web (and on StackOverflow), but none of them work, either. If I change the `_site` variable to...

- `Request.PhysicalPath`, nothing changes.
- `Server.MapPath(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath)`, nothing changes.
- `Server.MapPath(HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables.Get("SCRIPT_NAME"))`, nothing changes.
- `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables.Get("PATH_TRANSLATED")`, nothing changes.
- `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables.Get("SCRIPT_TRANSLATED")`, I get the exact same file path, but with `\\?\` at the front, and the application crashes, since canonical path is not a valid file path.
- `Server.MapPath(Request.Url.LocalPath.ToString())`, nothing changes.

So - how exactly can I get that `.aspx` file?

PS. There is [a somewhat similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973589/asp-net-4-webforms-routing-get-physical-page-handling-the-request), but it seems short, vague and poorly worded - SO's *Similar Questions* and myself think it's about getting the `.aspx` file, while its two answers think it's about getting the URL.

Comment: this might not be generic enough but possibly: `MyFile = Server.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath + "//sample1.aspx");`

Comment: @wazz Appending `.aspx` is an obvious workaround, but I'm curious to see if there's a way to check the date that won't come apart if I do literally anything with routes. Especially since we know that the framework KNOWS the file - to wit, it wouldn't be able to generate the page otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

try this below code:

```
string ASPXphysicalpath = Page.Request.PhysicalPath;
lblLastModified.Text = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(ASPXphysicalpath).ToString();
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, but `Request == Page.Request` returns `true`, so your solution is functionally identical to `Request.PhysicalPath`, which I have already tried.

Comment: @Dragomok PhysicalPath is for the aspx changes only, if something changes in the .cs behind it, this date wouldn't change.